# Is there a way to tell maven-Tomcat-plugin to listen to any Java file changes?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, java-ee-7

I've been recently learning Maven tutorials. This is where i came across Jetty Plugin, and a certain Configuration node in it which says to scan any java file changes of the concerned Application, so it essentially saves the time of building and restarting. Is there a similar way to tell Tomcat the same?

Comment: Don't know if there is a way to achieve this, but you can of course run tomcat in debug mode and recompile your java classes - **but** you cannot reload massive changes like adding classes, adding methods to classes or changing signatures.

Comment: Running Tomcat in debug mode isn't anywhere close to the answer. There's a solution though, to listen to any big java changes, which is JRebel, but again that's quite costly.  :)